# Decoding / Encoding Foreign Characters / UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec

Tags: python, json, twitter, decode, encode

I'm trying to export some tweets into json file but am getting errors. When I don't get errors it puts a 'b' character in my data and therefore messes up my json format. Here's my example and code:

here is the content of 'tweets':
['Мобильный телефон Xiaomi Redmi 6 64GB/4GB vs\n Мобильный телефон Huawei Honor 8X 64GB\n по параметрам совпадают на 86… ',
 'Xiaomi Rilis Redmi Note 7 Pro di India, Ini Spesifikasinya']

which I then convert to string:

```
tweets2=str(tweets)
```

and when I try to export it:

```
with open("tw_stream.jsonl", 'a') as f:
    f.write(tweets2)
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2- 
10: character maps to <undefined>
```

So the problem is I'm attempting to remove the 'b\' part of the string as it's not valid json, but in doing so I cannot encode the foreign characters to "utf-8"...

If someone can help it would be much appreciated.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use utf-8 encoding by passing param encoding="utf-8" in with..

Comment: Hi, the problem is that with encode/decode either it puts a 'b' in my data or it does not accept foreign characters